# Asp.Net MVC 3 Razor Rendering Bug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This one is strange...I have the following markup for a view using Razor view engine ASP.Net MVC 3 RC

```
            <p>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.FirstName)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.FirstName) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.FirstName)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.LastName)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.LastName) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.LastName)
                </div>
            </p>
```

The problem is that when it renders, the P tag is not surrounding the DIVs! It renders like this:

```
<p>
                </p><div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="Client.FirstName">First Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The First Name field is required." id="Client_FirstName" name="Client.FirstName" value="My FName" type="text"> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Client.FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="Client.LastName">Last Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Last Name field is required." id="Client_LastName" name="Client.LastName" value="My LName" type="text"> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Client.LastName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
```

What the heck is going on? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have link where this happens? I just threw the same code (allthough with a different form) on a page of mine and it works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a paragraph cannot contain other block level elements.  [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)

also check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong)

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, it seems like it is just standard browser behavior?

http://blog.programmingsolution.net/html/html-div-tag-inside-html-p-paragraph-tag-does-not-work-correctly/

Answer (score 2):

The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements e.g. DIV