# selecting all <h1> inside <p> using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm just trying to change the background color of all "h1" elments present under "p" as below but it's not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){



    $("p").find("h1").css("background-color","yellow");

});
```

Below is jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sukumar/X9yQL/4/

Comment: I think this fails because your markup is invalid

Comment: You should know that having a header tag inside a paragraph tag is invalid html. W3C validator wouldn't validate it.

Comment: Don't put block elements like `h1` in inline elements like `span`.

Comment: @Radu strangely, chromium doesn't have problem with h1 inside a span, but can't accept it inside a "p". doesn't know if it's standard compliant since you can play so easily with inline/block display in css

Comment: I don't believe that an `<h1>` tag is legal within a `<p>` tag, according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/h1. I tried to play with your fiddle to give you an answer, but it seems to be doing strange things with a header within a paragraph.

Comment: @BiAiB, most browsers will still render block elements within inline ones but it's bad practice. For that matter, headings within other headings isn't a good idea.. nor does it make sense :P

Comment: @Radu keeping semantics in your html structure is quite hard sometimes :p. Anyway I'm not sure of this but sometimes you have to do it in some CSS menus because IE won't understand :hover pseudo class in anything but anchors elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your html markup is invalid. Look at the markup generated with a debugger:

```
  <p>first
    </p><h1>first h1 <span>span1

        <h1>another h1 inside span</h1>
        </span>
    </h1>




<p></p>
```

seems you can't have a h* inside a p

Comment: Thanks a lot..I'm just experimenting. If i put <div> instead of <p> it's working.

Comment: @Sukumar you should learn about HTML elements, especially the difference between block and inline elements.

Comment: @Sukumar and use a debbuger (and learn to debug with it), it will surely spare lot of travels to here.

Comment: @BiAiB Ok. I'll do that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

See [Nesting block level elements inside the `<p>` tag… right or wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong/4291515#4291515):

> No, a paragraph element may not contain other block elements.
>
> [Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)
>
> A paragraph tag is intended for a block of text. If your elements is a
>   part of the text (and not block elements), it would be semantically
>   correct, otherwise not. A span tag with display:block is still a block
>   element.

Comment: Thanks, but send some upvotes to Guffa who posted the answer to the SO question I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers are going to remove the h1 tags from the p tags so it's not going to work. Using a span and styling it like an H1 will work just as good. Also your markup was a bit chaotic, I would suggest cleaning it up.