# CSS * Selector Weird treatment

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm doing some researches about browsers and their treat to the css and html codes, test this and see weird result and couldn't understand. it's a research. so it's not a real code.

I notice a problem when using CSS * selector. Let me explain:

See below example:

```
p * { color:red; }
```

It means that all the tags inside of a p element, must be red. 
some examples:

```
<p>
<div>
text <!-- Must be red but not !-->
</div>
<p>
text <!-- Must be red but not !-->
</p>
<span>
text <!-- Must be red but not !-->
</span>
</p>
```

Dose these problem has any reasons? Logical reasons?

Comment: [Huh?](http://jsfiddle.net/yQQZP/)

Comment: @YiJiang I've changed it. Now using P. Your'e right. Div has no problem :D

Comment: By the way, there once was a W3C spec that did allow block elements in paragraphs. Rest in peace, XHTML 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The W3 XHTML validator will ding you for using nested `p` tags. 
Think about it for a brief moment: "a paragraph within a paragraph.". Syntactically, a `div` inside a `p` is invalid in all standards of HTML. Moreover, when using a conforming HTML parser, it is impossible to place a `div` element inside a `p` in the DOM because the opening `div` tag will automatically close the `p` element. You can see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong)

You can however use inline tags such as `span` if you want to style elements in your paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I assume its because of the poor markup. Browsers tend to close certain tags. You have a p tag wrapping another p tag. So the browser might close it for you and start a new one, which is possibly messing up your CSS selector.

```
<p><div>should be red?</div></p>
<p>just text won't be red</p>
```

Comment: The div won't be red either, for the same reason.

Comment: And browsers "tend to close certain tags" because they have to - it's a hard requirement of the specs. What they should do with the dangling `</p>` in the example however, that is something else.