# PHP generated HTML is closing an HTML tag on it's own

Tags: php, html, tags

In my website I have a section where I generate HTML from a twitter feed. Here is the php code that wraps the section in HTML:

```
    <p class="columns">
    <?
    require ("twitter-feed.php");
    echo generatetwitter();
    ?>
    </p>
```

the generatetwitter(); method returns this as a string:

```
    <li class="twitter">&#x201c;@<a class=" " href="http://twitter.com/lecrae">lecrae</a>: If people throw stones at you, pick em up and build something. <a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23stayfocused" title="#stayfocused" class=" ">#stayfocused</a>&#x201d;</li>
```

When the page generates it shows the code properly in the "View Source" option of Chrome and Firefox, but when I do "inspect element" it shows this

```
    <p class="columns"></p>
    <li class="twitter">...</li>
    <p></p>
```

So the class CSS isn't getting applied to the twitter feed. I need the twitter feed to be in the p tags with the class defined.

Some points:

- generatetwitter() returns the HTML in a string
- I've tried having twitter-feed.php (the generatetwitter() method) echoing out the HTML directly, but it makes no difference. I've had the same results every time.
- when the generatetwitter() method is overridden to return only a normal string "eg return "test";" it works normally.
- It seems that this doesn't work if the generatetwitter() method returns anything but regular text (excluding HTML).

Comment: Probably because your HTML is malformed and the browser is trying to correct it, where is your <UL> or <OL> starting tag for your <LI> element? Also, what doctype are you using?

Comment: Thanks for catching that, but it didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: try using DIV or SPAN instead, there are rules as to what elements can be nested inside of Paragraph tags, I believe the rule is not block level elements inside of a <P>

Comment: THANK YOU!! I changed it to <span> and it worked. I've been working on this all day...

Comment: Neat, please accept my reply as the answer to your question, I also found a similar case for you to read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain block level tags will close opened paragraph tags when nested, try using DIV or SPAN instead of the P tag as per my earlier comments.

[Nesting block level elements inside the <p> tag... right or wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong)

Comment: That link explained it well. Thank you very much.