# How to disable jQuery closing the P-tag for you?

Tags: javascript, jquery, paragraph

```
var wrapper = $('<p><div class="text">Hello World</div></p>');
console.log(wrapper.html());
```

Becomes

```
<p></p><div class="text">SOMETHING</div><p></p>
```

How can you avoid the HTML being messed up like that?

---

ANSWER : I did not realize putting a DIV inside a paragraph was invalid HTML.

Comment: It's invalid to have a div inside a p: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong .

Comment: *How can you avoid the HTML being messed up like that?* Create valid HTML :P The browser will always try to correct invalid HTML...

Answer (score 6):

`div` is not supported within `p`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var wrapper = $('<p></p>').html('<div class="text">Hello World</div>');
console.log(wrapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var wrapper = $( '<p></p>').append(
    $( '<div></div>' )
        .text( 'Hello World' )
        .attr( 'class', 'text' )
);
```

Or just using `innerHTML` from your comments:

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('p');
wrapper.innerHTML = '<div class="text">Hello World</div>';
console.log( wrapper );​
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/R9kXU/

Comment: I appreciate your reply however I am loading html content from an external source and try to add that to the DOM, but all P get messed up like that.