# CSS-descendent selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to know difference between these two lines:

```
p.intro a{color=# ff99ff;}
p .intro a{color=# ff99ff;}
```

In first example there is no space between `p` and `.intro`, while in second example there is space between them.

I want an explanation with examples.

Comment: Have you looked at the spec? There's an explanation with an example there. http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors#descendant-combinators

Comment: Your CSS rules are invalid, you should be using colons (`:`)  instead of equal signs.

Comment: And you can't have spaces between `#` and the rest of the hex color values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rule is for

```
<p class="intro"><a href="#">some</a></p>
```

Second is for

```
<p><span class="intro"><a href="#">some</a></span></p>
```

Answer (score 5):

The first is the class given to the p item.

```
<p class="intro">
    <a href="#">Item</a>
</p>
```

The second is the class given to the p tag's child.

```
<p>
    <span class="intro">
        <a href="#">Item</a>
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: div inside p is kinda a no-no...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong

Comment: @mdmullinax This is just an example and div is the most generically used tag.

Comment: examples frequently make it into production, span is just as generically used and a good fit

Comment: Eh, I figured it was okay since both were block-level elements. I'll change it though.

Comment: `p` is known for being a block-level element that doesn't allow any other block-level elements inside it. @Mike Brant: If you read the post that mdmullinax links to, you'll realize that such an example will quite simply not work, making it pretty useless as an example.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'd like to consider myself an advanced web dev, but I am still learning stuff every day. There's nothing wrong with doing stuff correctly haha.

Answer (score 1):

OK, first `p.intro a { color: #ff99ff; }`

```
<p class="intro">This <a>link</a> is colored #ff99ff.</p>

<p>But <a>this one</a> is not.</p>
```

Any `a` tag within a `p` that has the `intro` class gets colored.

Then `p .intro a { color: #ff99ff; }`

```
<p class="intro">This <a>link</a> is colored normally.</p>

<p>And so is <a>this one</a>, but <span class="intro"><a>this one</a> is colored #ff99ff.</span></p>

<div>Also, <span class="intro"><a>this link</a></span> doesn't get colored either.</div>
```

Here, only `a` tags that are within *anything* that has the `intro` class, which is itself within some `p`, gets colored.

Comment: I understood now. Thanks a lot for your quick right and good explanation with example and meaning. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

The first will affect all `a` tags that are descendants of `p` tags that have the class `intro`.

The second will affect all `a` tags that are both descendants of an element (any) with the class `intro` AND, at the same time, descendants of a `p` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
p.intro a
```

This finds all `<a>` that are decenents of `<p class="intro">`.

```
p .intro a
```

This finds all `<a>` that are decenents of any element with the class `intro` that are decendants of a `<p>`.

Comment: Why is your mane of a different color in your profile description? (Highly off-topic, but I couldn't help asking.)

Comment: @BoltClock: (in character) Because I wanted to dye it pink!  It's EXTREME!  (IRL) Because I originally had it pink, but I liked black better.  I decided to keep both images for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The first case will select all A tags there are nested somewhere below a P tag with class "intro".

```
<p class="intro"><div><a>This is selected</a></div></p>
```

The second case will select all A tags that are nested somewhere below any sort of DOM element with a class of "intro" which in turn is nested somewhere in the a P tag.

```
<p><div><div class="intro"><div><a>This is selected</a></div></div></div></p>
```

Note that the nested element do not have to be directly below the preceding elements in the selector.  They just need to be nested somewhere within the preceding items in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
p.intro a{
  color=# ff99ff; 
}
```

This will effect for `<a>` that are inside 
example:

```
<p class="intro">
    <a href="#">one</a>
</p>
```

and

```
p .intro a{
  color=# ff99ff;
}
```

This will effect for `<a>` that are inside the class `intro` which is inside `<p>`

example:

```
<p>
    <span class="intro">
        <a href="#">one</a>
    </span>
</p>
```