# Styling tags within tags confusion

Tags: css

I am having a rather difficult time understanding this type of css selector show below, or at least how to apply.

```
p .intro a { color: yellow }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
p .intro a { color: yellow }
```

It would style any (reading from right to left)

- `a` tag
- which is a descendant of any tag with a class (dot is a class selector) `intro`
- which is a descendant of `p` tag

Example (note that the elements are not direct children, but descendants):

```
<p>
    <span>
        <span class="intro">
            <span>
                <a href="#">I am yellow</a>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</p>
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/9p7qD/2/)

Comment: I understand now, but this is not working correctly in my markup for some reason.  I even copied/pasted your code.

Comment: Try making a http://jsfiddle.net to show what are you trying to do. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9p7qD/2/

Comment: I just tried jsfiddle, and the color is still blue.  What is going on with this code?

Comment: Show your code in jsfiddle. I gave you an explanation, example and working jsfiddle, that's pretty much all I can do without seeing your code...

Comment: div is not a valid child of p (therefore p is closed before div is opened and div becomes not a descendant, but a sibling of p). Try using span: http://jsfiddle.net/aLgkP/1/

Comment: I am even more confused now.  In my code it "looks" like div is a child of p, but it isn't valid child?

Comment: div is a block element. p is also a block element, but it's a bit special, it can't have block elements as children, it can only have inline elements as children. Therefore browser will move div out of p element. You can read more in the spec: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element

Comment: Okay thats were the confusion was.  I didn't know that the p couldn't have block level elements at all.

Comment: You might want to mark this answer as correct (the same goes for other questions you have asked before).

Answer (score 2):

This selector would match HTML similar to this:

```
<p>
    <span class="intro">
        <a href="#">I am yellow</a>
    </span>
</p>
```

Basically, a `a` tag inside of a tag with a class of `intro` inside of a `p` tag. They don't have to be direct children.

Answer (score 0):

Your jsFiddle example fails because of symantics. Peep this: [Nesting block level elements inside the <p> tag... right or wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong)

So what you can do is change your markup to, for example:

```
<p>
    <span class="intro">
        <a href="#">I AM yellow</a>
    </span>
</p>
```

or

```
<div>
    <div class="intro">
        <a href="#">I AM yellow</a>
    </div>
</div>
```