# Twitter bootstrap "lead" not working with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap along with simple_form in Rails. For some reason I cannot get the Bootstrap class="lead" to function. I see in the rendered HTML some additional classes which I assume come from simple_form. How can I get the two to play together?

This is my code:

```
<p class="lead">
  <%= sentence.input :dialog, :input_html => { :class => "span8" },
              :placeholder => "Enter your sentence here", :label => false %>              
</p>
```

And this is the rendered HTML:

```
<p class="lead">
  <div class="control-group string optional">
  <div class="controls"><input class="string optional span8" id="dialog_catagory_dialogs_attributes_0_dialog" name="dialog_catagory[dialogs_attributes][0][dialog]" placeholder="Enter your sentence here" size="50" type="text" />
 </div>
 </div>
</p>
```

**EDIT**
I've tried various options, including using the rendered HTML, like this and removing the divs. Still not working.

```
<p class="lead">
  <input class="string optional span8" id="dialog_catagory_dialogs_attributes_0_dialog" name="dialog_catagory[dialogs_attributes][0][dialog]" placeholder="Enter your sentence here 2" size="50" type="text" />
</p>
```

**output**

```
<p class="lead">
   <input id="dialog_catagory_dialogs_attributes_0_dialog" name="dialog_catagory[dialogs_attributes][0][dialog]" size="30" type="text" />
</p>
```

Comment: When you installed simple_form, did you pass in the --bootstrap option?  `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`

Comment: Yes I did. I've tried bouncing the web server but no difference.

Comment: Would the enclosed classes like 'controls' be overriding the bootstrap class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem: Placing a `div` inside of a `p` element implicitly closes the `p` tag in standards-confirming browsers. ( [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong) )

You can see (and modify locally, if you wish) the behavior of Simple Form's Bootstrap generators in [this file on Github](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/generators/simple_form/templates/config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb).

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. So to use a different class I would need to modify the simple form source? eg:  ba.use :foobar,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'p', :class => 'lead' } ?

Comment: Sure - or use the [deface gem](https://github.com/railsdog/deface) to filter the output. But the easiest thing would be to not use the form helper. Just hard-code exactly what you want, nested just as you want it. You can use the output of the form helper as-is as a starting point.

Comment: The hard-coding sounds like the solution, but I'm not sure exactly how to do it.

Comment: Actually, you already have, haha. Start with the second snippet of your original post - the rendered HTML. That's the output of the form helper.