# HTML5: Reference for valid tags inside other tags

Tags: html, validation

A while back I was using the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) for HTML5 and I was experimenting with a tag to replace the deprecated `<tt>` tag. I typed this little example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Valid tags inside other tags</title></head>
<body>

<p>Inside paragraph you cannot use <pre>preformated text</pre></p>

</body>
</html>
```

And got this error:

> Line 6, Column 66: No p element in scope but a p end tag seen.

But when I changed the `<pre>` tag for the `<code>` tag, no error was raised.

I suppose this is because you cannot have preformated text inside a paragraph, but I had no luck searching for a regex or something that can point me to valid tags inside other tags.

Anyone can point me to such resource?

EDIT:

Turns out that I suck at reading documentation and I haven't look at Block-level elements. So, now the question is, How can I know which are valid inline elements and how to use block-level elements inside other block-level elements?

Comment: Why can't you wrap your text inside a `div`? maybe this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong

Comment: @eric.itzhak Ok, I'm checking it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With HTML5 the old categories of `block` and `inline` have been extended and replaced by a [new content model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html).  The distinction between `block` and `inline` is now something which only really matters [in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display).

If you look at [any particular element in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-code-element.html#the-code-element) you'll see that it has a list of [content categories](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#kinds-of-content) it belongs to, the category in which the element can be used and the allowed content model of its descendants.

The [`p` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-p-element.html#the-p-element) has a content model of phrasing content, therefore it cannot contain a [`pre` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-pre-element.html#the-pre-element) because that can be used only where flow content is expected.