# How to work with CSS Child Selector in a List?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I tested the following code, and don't know why the same HTML Structure is not working in a list. Inside the `div` container with the `p` everything works fine. Only the `p` inside `.level1` class gets `bold`. But same structure inside a `ul` doesn't work. Why is also the `li` element inside the `.level2` class `bold`?

```
<ul class="level1">
  <li>Level 1</li>
  <li>Level 1</li>
  <li>Level 1
    <ul class="level2">
      <li>Level 2</li>
      <li>Level 2</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Level 1</li>
</ul>


<div class="level1">
  <p>Level 1</p>
  <p>Level 1</p>
  <p>Level 1
    <div class="level2">
      <p>Level 2</p>
      <p>Level 2</p>
    </div>
  </p>
  <p>Level 1</p>
</div>

.level1 > li {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.level1 > p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="level1">
  <li>Level 1</li>
  <li>Level 1</li>
  <li>Level 1               // Started here because of this 
    <ul class="level2">     // class2 ul elements are considered as li of class1
      <li>Level 2</li>
      <li>Level 2</li>
      </ul>
  </li>                   
  <li>Level 1</li>
</ul>
```

whereas here, your second question,

> I would like to add **[@defau1t answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8398003/1671639)** :
>   In short, it is impossible toplace a `<div>` element inside a `<p>` in the DOM because
>   the opening `<div>` tag will automatically close the `<p>` element.

```
<div class="level1">
  <p>Level 1</p>
  <p>Level 1</p>
  <p>Level 1                 //P tag can't have div tag inside it.  
    <div class="level2">     //Hence it didn't worked
      <p>Level 2</p>
      <p>Level 2</p>
    </div>
  </p>
  <p>Level 1</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code you are tageting all the li's tags from the ul with the class 
`.level1` including the li's of the ul `.level2`, to fix this just re-target the li's of the `.level2` ul and return the `font-weight : 400 //or normal`, see this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rsm23/s3CmF/

Hope I helped You

Comment: He's actually not selecting wrong. The `.level1 > li` selects all `li` elements with a parent (a direct parent) with a class `level1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your example with `<div>` elements inside `<p>` elements is invalid, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong/). W3C also specifies [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1):

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

Since `<div>` elements are block-level elements, you can't place them inside `<p>` elements. So... never do that again.

On to your problem. Your example with `<li>` items works perfect according to the specifications. Your selector `.level1 > li` selects the li elements correctly, however, the `<li>Level 2</li>` elements simply inherit the `font-weight` property. You would have to add a css rule

```
.level2 > li {
    font-weight:initial;
}
```

or set it to another value, if you want to.