# ember.js html output broken

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I'm having a lot of troubles trying to debug why the following is failing:

Given the following template:

```
<p class='navbar-text pull-right header-user-info'>
{{#if currentUser.isSignedIn}}
  {{#if view.isDashboard}}
    <img {{bindAttr src="currentUser.avatar" title="currentUser.fullName"}} class='avatar'>
  {{else}}
    {{view PR2.NavigationSelectMenuView selectedBinding="view.selected"}}
    {{navigationIcon selectedBinding="view.selected"}}
  {{/if}}
  <span class='user-info'>
    aangemeld als {{currentUser.fullName}}
    {{#link-to 'session.destroy'}}log uit{{/link-to}}
  </span>
{{/if}}
</p>
```

and the PR2.NavigationSelectMenuView as follows:

```
PR2.NavigationSelectMenuView = Em.View.extend({
  tagName: 'ul'
});
```

When I go to the dashboard (and view.isDashboard is true), the image is rendered, and the else is not rendered, as it should. If i then navigate to another part of the application, the isDashboard becomes false and the navigationIcon and navigationSelectMenu are rendered within the p-tag as it should. So far everything is fine.

The problem comes when I enter my application directly from another route, and skip the dashboard, for example, i go to /settings. isDashboard is false and the 2 views are rendered instead. But the html output is broken then:

HTML output when navigating through the dashboard (the good output), all the metamorph tags are nested properly:

```
<p class="navbar-text pull-right header-user-info">
  <script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
  <script id="metamorph-1-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script><script id="metamorph-1-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
  <ul id="ember511" class="ember-view"></ul>
  <span id="ember514" class="ember-view avatar settings-icon"></span>
  <script id="metamorph-1-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
  <span class="user-info">
    <span id="i18n-0">aangemeld als</span> <script id="metamorph-2-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>username<script id="metamorph-2-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    <a id="ember424" class="ember-view loading" href="#"><span id="i18n-1">log uit</span></a>
  </span>
  <script id="metamorph-0-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
</p>
```

HTML output when navigating directly to another page (the bad output), the metamorphs start in the p-tag, but then the p is closed, then the content, and then another p-tag.

```
<p class="navbar-text pull-right header-user-info">
  <script id="metamorph-0-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
  <script id="metamorph-1-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
</p>
<ul id="ember444" class="ember-view"></ul>
<span id="ember447" class="ember-view avatar settings-icon"></span>
<script id="metamorph-1-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
<span class="user-info">
  <span id="i18n-0">aangemeld als</span>
  <script id="metamorph-2-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>username<script id="metamorph-2-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
  <a id="ember448" class="ember-view loading" href="#"><span id="i18n-1">log uit</span></a>
</span>
<script id="metamorph-0-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
<p></p>
```

The strange thing is, if I leave out this line:

```
{{view PR2.NavigationSelectMenuView selectedBinding="view.selected"}}
```

Everything works fine

Comment: After some debugging by removing code, I found out that this only happens when the root tag is a paragraph, if I change it to <div class="navbar-text pull-right header-user-info></div> it works fine.

Comment: In html you can't put a block element, inside of an inline element. You will have some layout issues. Give a look in @intuitivepixel answer and this relative question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is clearly because the `p` (paragraph) tag does not support nested `script` tags inside.

Taken from: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html

> A p element’s end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by an **address, article, aside, blockquote, dir, div, dl, fieldset, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hr, menu, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table**, or **ul** element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an a element.

This is also the reason why when you use `div` everything works fine. IMHO this is not an ember issue, but rather related to the limitations the `p` tag has.

Therefore the way to go would be to wrap stuff in a `div` and format it the way you would do with the paragraph.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not worded correctly. <p> tags with nested script tags seem to work fine. However, on the first encounter of one of the elements bolded in the quotes, the <p> tag will automatically close. In rrooding's case that element is the <ul> element. Finally, we have a hanging </p> tag which the browser fixes by replacing that with <p></p>.