# Float right check boxes, buttons and inputbox

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I reckon it must be fairly simple but i can't seem to figure out how to get my floats right. The picture shows what i want vs what i have. If you provide an answer please provide the logic also. thanks.

```
        <div id="racks" style="overflow:auto">
        <div id="selStat">
        <p>No station selected</p>
        </div>
        <hr id="hrtest">
        <div id="rackAction">
        <p>Choose the type of card, then select which action to perform.</p>
        <div id="radio">
        Type:
        <div class="fr">
        <input type="radio" id="radioS" name="radio"><label for="radioS">S</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radioP" name="radio"><label for="radioP">P</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radioV" name="radio"><label for="radioV">V</label>
        </div></div>
        <p>Cardnumber:  <input id="cardNum" class="fr" type="number" size="1"/> </p>
        <p>Action: 
        <div class="fr">
        <button onClick="addRack()" type="button">Add</button>
        <button onClick="deleteRack()" type="button">Delete</button>
        </div></p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

CSS is as follow:

```
 .fr{
    float:right;
    }
```

[image: image what I want vs What I have]

Comment: You shouldn't have a `div` inside of a `p` tag.  Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong)

Comment: seems like you should put "Action" inside the same div as the buttons. Personally I'd try to bust this out quickest by using divs instead of <p> then just put all the content for a single row in 1 div, then do the floating inside that.

Comment: can you post your css complete? and maybe make a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically, you can't have a `div` inside of a `p` tag.  On that topic, check this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong).  To get the elements on the same line, you can place the "Action" text in a seperate `div`, and float it left.

The HTML:

```
    <div id="racks" style="overflow:auto">
      <div id="selStat">
        <p>No station selected</p>
      </div>

      <hr id="hrtest">

      <div id="rackAction">
        <p>Choose the type of card, then select which action to perform.</p>
        <div id="radio">
          Type:
          <div class="fr">
            <input type="radio" class="margin-bottom" id="radioS" name="radio"><label for="radioS">S</label>
            <input type="radio" class="margin-bottom" id="radioP" name="radio"><label for="radioP">P</label>
            <input type="radio" class="margin-bottom" id="radioV" name="radio"><label for="radioV">V</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <p>Cardnumber:  <input id="cardNum" class="fr" type="number" size="1"/> </p>

        <div class="fl">Action:</div> 

        <div class="fr">
          <button onClick="addRack()" type="button">Add</button>
          <button onClick="deleteRack()" type="button">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.fr{
  float:right;
}
.fl {
  float:left;
}
.margin-bottom {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/N79uP/).

**Edit:**

As per the comments, you can add a class to the radio buttons in question, and add additional margins or padding to the bottom of the radio buttons.  I have updated the code to include the class additions and the CSS.

Comment: Seems promising, however it does not keep in mind the added height of the jQuery UI Radio's: http://imgur.com/jpcEBEC

Comment: Is that image how it is displaying with the updated code?  How are you wanting that changed?

Comment: Yes it is, as you can see, the radio's are somehow ignoring the margin/padding a p-tag would normally give (as you can see for the pag tag with action: add delete in it)

Comment: Add a class to the buttons, and use it to add additional margins or paddings.  I updated my answer to reflect that.  I used 10px as an example, but you can adjust that to the desired height.

Comment: Thanks,     <p class="padTop">Cardnumber:
      <input id="cardNum" class="fr" type="number" size="1" />
     </p> did the track, i added top padding to the cardnumber p tag