# Display div on hover with CSS selector "+" combinater

Tags: css, html

I am trying to get a div to show on hover using the "+" combinater and it's not working. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="about-team">
<div class="client">
    <div class="about-team-left">   <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>

    </div>
    <div class="about-team-right">
        <p>Just writing a quick note to tell you how very happy we are with our new addition to our family... Our "Molly" is such an adorable puppy... <a id="rm">READ MORE</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="readmore1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, qui est quo consequuntur esse iure tempora. Hic tenetur nemo repudiandae quae unde sed aliquid deleniti ad! Facilis, reprehenderit culpa mollitia.</div>
```

CSS

```
.readmore1 {
display: none;
}

#rm:hover + .readmore1 {
display: block;
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
}
```

JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9zDEp/3/

Thanks!

Comment: That's because they're not siblings. Either change your markup or use JavaScript to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html structure didn't work with the **anchor** and **div** inside the **p** but you can switch the text to be inside a **span** so they wrap:

```
<div class="about-team">
<div class="client">
    <div class="about-team-left"> <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" /></a>

    </div>
    <div class="about-team-right"> 
        <span>Just writing a quick note to tell you how very happy we are with our new addition to our family... Our "Molly" is such an adorable puppy...</span>  
        <a id="rm">READ MORE</a>

        <div class="readmore">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, qui est quo consequuntur esse iure tempora. Hic tenetur nemo repudiandae quae unde sed aliquid deleniti ad! Facilis, reprehenderit culpa mollitia.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I would consider using a more generalized CSS that doesn't rely on ID fields, like this:

```
.readmore {
display: none;
}

a:hover + div.readmore {
display: block;
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9zDEp/15/

Comment: I noticed that you and the other response both removed the <p> tag. I noticed that if I just put <div class="readmore"> inside the <p> after the <a id="rm">READ MORE</a> it will not work...

Comment: It looks like the nesting of a div in a p tag is invalid according to HTML standards. Violating this rule, may be why the expected hover did not work. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4291608/904713 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change markup to show them as *adjacent selectors* like

```
<div class="about-team-right">Just writing a quick note to tell you how very happy we are with our new addition to our family... Our "Molly" is such an adorable puppy... </div>
   <a id="rm">READ MORE</a>
   <div class="readmore1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, qui est quo consequuntur esse iure tempora. Hic tenetur nemo repudiandae quae unde sed aliquid deleniti ad! Facilis, reprehenderit culpa mollitia.</div>
</div>
```

[What does the “+” (plus sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1139763/1671639)

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zDEp/12/)

---

Here is an [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9zDEp/16/) another approach using Javascript

Comment: You didn't close the first div :)

Comment: I noticed that you and the other response both removed the <p> tag. I noticed that if I just put <div class="readmore"> inside the <p> after the <a id="rm">READ MORE</a> it will not work...

Comment: @YKB because it is not possible to have `div` tag within `p`.  That is the only reason.

Comment: @YKB Here read this question [Why <p> tag can't contain <div> tag inside it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8397852/1671639) to find out the reason.