# Extra <p></p> tags when outputting MySql data using a PHP Loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I output MySql data using a php while loop, I seem to get extra `<p></p>` tags, or the `<p>` tag closes before it should.

```
while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
    echo '<p>';
    echo '<div>Some Data</div>';
    echo '<div>More Data</div>';
    echo '</p>';
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
<p></p>
<div>Some Data</div>
<div>More Data</div>

<p></p>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<p>
<div>Some Data</div>
<div>More Data</div>
</p>
```

Can you see why this is happening? I check using FireBug, and see the above. When I check the page source in Firefox, I see a red `</p>` tag which is supposed to be a stray, but all tags are actually properly closed.

Can you please help with this?

Comment: This line `echo '<div>More Data</div>` should be `echo '<div>More Data</div>';`, code in your question even shows this (echo is red)

Comment: You are missing an ending quote and semi-colon on your third line of the while loop, that is what is causing the problem.

Comment: May be a problem trying to nest block elements within <p> - see the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong

Comment: @IanKenney So, I should not be placing <div>'s inside <p>s then?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct syntax

```
while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
    echo '<p>';
    echo '<div>Some Data</div>';
    echo '<div>More Data</div>';
    echo '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Still the same. That was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to use block level elements like `<div>` inside of a `<p>`. Your browser fixes this mistake for you by ending the `<p>` before openeing the `<div>` - and Firebug displayes the fixed HTML.

It would be wise to change your `<p>` to `<div class="something">`.

Answer (score 1):

The following is taken from the [HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1):

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself).

`<div>` is a block-level element.

Most browsers, if they encounter an opening `<div>` tag within a `<p>` tag, will automatically close off the `<p>` with a `</p>` before handling the `<div>`.

So that's the phenomenon you're seeing.  Your first `<p>` is followed by the first `<div>`, which is then closed off before the 2 lines of `<div>` content are handled.  And then your final closing `</p>`, which looks to the browser like a closing tag that never had an opening tag (because, remember, the first `<p>` has already been closed off) is handled by the browser as `<p></p>`.

To demonstrate, you can view this HTML in your browser:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
<div>hello</div>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you open the browser's inspector, which shows what the actual DOM representation of this HTML looks like, you should see something like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p></p>
    <div>hello</div>
    <p></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch() ){

  if( ! empty( $row ) ) {  //make sure u skip empty lines with an if condition

    echo "<p> \n <div>some data </div> \n <div> More DAta </div> \n </p> " ;

  }

}
```

please watch out for firebug and firefox as if there is missing  they tend to try to figure it out them selfs and add it; so what you see might not be the actual source code.

you need to click **right click--> view source** to see the actual output without firefox edittings