# Filtering woocommerce_short_description removes the P closing tag

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

If I filter the "woocommerce_short_description" hook, as shown in the code below, it ends up "eating" the final `<p>` tag (which is put by WordPress actually):

```
function seemore_filter_short_description( $desc ){
global $product;

if ( is_single( $product->id ) )
    $desc .= '<div class="seemore"><a href="#fullDescription"> '.__( 'See more...', 'woocommerce-seemore').'</a></div>';
return $desc;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'seemore_filter_short_description',0,1 );
```

Here is the result:

```
<div itemprop="description">
<p>O Chá de Amora Miura é riquíssimo em cálcio, potássio, magnésio, ferro natural, proteína, fibra, zinco e levedura.<br />
Este Chá de Amora Miúra não é remédio é complemento alimentar, muito utilizado pelos orientais.
<div class="seemore"><a href="#fullDescription"> Veja mais&#8230;</a></div>
</div>
```

And if I deactivate the plugin the `</p>` is shown again after 'orientais'

How can I get my div to be inserted before the P closing tag? I actually wanted my "See more" starting after the last word, what would be the best (and easiest) way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You may not actually need to close the `<p>` tag. Also, regarding syntactically correct HTML you can't place a `<div>` inside of a `<p>` tag. [Here's some more information on div nesting in p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong)

If you need to have the `</p>` tag you could add it to your `$desc` variable before the `<div...`

Comment: I see, but why is end tag being "eaten"?