# AngularJS ng-switch throws error on <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I'm quite new to AngularJS, just started with it and I came across `ng-switch`, where I noticed that this works only on `<div>` tag, like

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="switchController">
    <div ng-switch on="myData.text">
      <p ng-switch-when="1">Switch To 1</p>
      <p ng-switch-when="2">Switch To 2</p>
      <p ng-switch-default>Switch To Default</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

when I declare it as below it throws an error!

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="switchController">
    <p ng-switch on="myData.text">
      <p ng-switch-when="1">Switch To 1</p>
      <p ng-switch-when="2">Switch To 2</p>
      <p ng-switch-default>Switch To Default</p>
    </p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
        .controller("switchController", function($scope) {
            $scope.myData = {};
            $scope.myData.text = 2;
            console.log($scope.myData.text);
});
```

**[PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/iBZj6ASzs0y4GyHyMbFm?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, posted my comment too early.

This doesn't work because nested `<p>` tags are invalid HTML.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="switchController">
    <p ng-switch on="myData.text">
      <p ng-switch-when="1">Switch To 1</p>
      <p ng-switch-when="2">Switch To 2</p>
      <p ng-switch-default>Switch To Default</p>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `<p>Hello one<p>Hello two</p></p>` works good. Why do you say nested `<p>` are not valid?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong

Comment: However, interestingly, there is nothing about it in the HTML5 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html/grouping-content.html#the-p-element (but through other sources, it is still disallowed)