# Why if I use $("<p>something</p>") add one more <p></p> in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I met now a strange behaviour (or normal and I didn't know about this?) in jQuery for the following code:

```
$("<p><div>item1</div></p>")
```

and the result is:

```
[<p>​</p>​, <div>​item1​</div>​, <p>​</p>​]
```

Why last `<p></p>` is added and where come from ?

Comment: Probably because a `div` can't be placed inside a `p`?!

Comment: because `<p>` tags can't contain `<div>` tags

Comment: Because http://stackoverflow.com/a/4291608/1245497

Comment: and actually it's not the last `<p></p>` that is added. It's the </p> left from the div and the <p> right from the div that have been added, to correct for the error

Answer (score 2):

`<p><div></div></p>` is not valid HTML and the browser is well within its rights to attempt to correct it by closing the `<p>` before the `<div>`

Comment: Where does the last `p` come from?

Comment: @SalmanA - It's the `</p>` left from the div as well as the `<p>` right from the div that have been added, to correct for the error and make sure all tags are properly closed