# Unexpected behavior of CSS Child combinator (>)

Tags: html, css, dom, css-selectors

I have a basic HTML structure here. The rule `div > p` selects the `<p>` element directly inside the `<div>`, which is expected. But it also selects the `<p>` element inside another `<p>` that itself is inside the `<div>`. I can't figure out the logic here.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>
    P#1, in the div.
    <p>P#2, in the P that's in the div.</p>
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div > p {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: This is because the browser thinks that nested `<p>` tags in the text input are invalid HTML5, and "auto-corrects" them into non-nested `<p>` tags. You can confirm it by using the inspector (actually there are 3 `p` elements in the browser output, the third one has no content). The resulting outerHTML of the div element is like `"<div>\n  <p>\n    P#1, in the div.\n    </p><p>P#2, in the P that's in the div.</p>\n  <p></p>\n</div>"`. It automatically closes the first `p` tag before opening the second `p` tag. And finally when the last `</p>` is reached, there is no open `p`, thus the empty `p`

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015804/nesting-p-wont-work-while-nesting-div-will (nesting p won't work even though nesting div works) Another thing you shouldn't do is trying to nest `<div>` within a `<p>`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835895/div-nested-in-p?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you. It seems my understanding of HTML is also lacking. It auto closes the first P tag which means the "nested" P is now a direct children also.