# Get element within element (no class/id)

Tags: javascript, html

How can I select the paragraph that's within a paragraph, without a class or ID to identify it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<body>

    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h2>Goodbye</h2>
    <ul>
        <li id="highlight">List Item 1</li>
        <li class="som">List Item 2</li>
        <li class="bolded">List Item 3</li>
        <li class="bolded">List Item 4 <p>Testing123</p></li>
    </ul>
    <p>
        This is an <strong>awesome</strong> paragraph!
    </p>
    <a href="htps://www.google.com">Link to Google</a>
    <a href="https://www.bing.com">Link to Bing</a>
    <p>
        Click a button!
        <button class="button">Click here!</button>
        <p>Haven't been clicked...</p>
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="domManipulate.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I select the `<p>Haven't been clicked...</p>` tags?

I've tried `var under_btn_txt = document.querySelector("p p");` and `... = document.getElementsByTagName("p")`.

I'd think the first works, because `document.querySelector("li p");` does get the `Testing123` text...

The second method does, technically, get it. I need to access it with, say `under_btn_txt[2]`. But what if I don't know necessarily what `p` that's in, to know I need the second index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html here is invalid. `p` is a self closing tag and it cannot nest another `p`.More information [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong).

Add a class to the parent p element and for nesting use `span`.Then use `querySelector` and `getElementsByTagName` & `innerHTML` to get the content

```js
var getPTag = document.querySelector(".click");
var getChild = getPTag.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
console.log(getChild)
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h2>Goodbye</h2>
<ul>
  <li id="highlight">List Item 1</li>
  <li class="som">List Item 2</li>
  <li class="bolded">List Item 3</li>
  <li class="bolded">List Item 4
    <p>Testing123</p>
  </li>
</ul>
<p>
  This is an <strong>awesome</strong> paragraph!
</p>
<a href="htps://www.google.com">Link to Google</a>
<a href="https://www.bing.com">Link to Bing</a>
<p class="click">Click a button!<button class="button">Click here!</button>
  <span>Haven't been clicked...</span>
</p>
```

Comment: That makes sense! I didn't know the <p> within <p> is illegal. (I'll need to find a way to validate my HTML in SublimeText...).  Also, with @HassanImam's answer will need to see what the difference is using a span vs. setting up a div. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A paragraph element may not contain other block elements. That means you can't nest `p` inside another `p` tag, since `p` is block elements.

You have to modify your HTML. You can replace parent `p` with `div` and access `p` tag inside it using `div p`.

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('div p')[0])
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h2>Goodbye</h2>
<ul>
    <li id="highlight">List Item 1</li>
    <li class="som">List Item 2</li>
    <li class="bolded">List Item 3</li>
    <li class="bolded">List Item 4 <p>Testing123</p></li>
</ul>
<p>
    This is an <strong>awesome</strong> paragraph!
</p>
<a href="htps://www.google.com">Link to Google</a>
<a href="https://www.bing.com">Link to Bing</a>
<div>
    Click a button!
    <button class="button">Click here!</button>
    <p>Haven't been clicked...</p>
</div>
```