# Retrieve text in the `<p></p>` tag that contains `<div></div>`

Tags: html, r, xpath, rvest

While web-scraping research articles with R, I encountered the HTML code where a `<div></div>` tag is nested within a `<p></p>` tag, which apparently is [ungrammatical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong).

I nevertheless wish to retrieve the entire text within the `<p></p>` tag.

If I simply do the following, whatever text that comes after the closing `</div>` tag is ignored, because apparently a closing `</p>` and a line break are automatically inserted before the `<div>` tag.

In the example below, what I want to retrieve is "text1text3" rather than just "text1".

```
> library("rvest"); library("tidyverse")
> x <- read_html("<p>text1<div>text2</div>text3</p>")
> x %>% html_nodes("p") %>% html_text()
[1] "text1"
> x
{xml_document}
<html>
[1] <body>\n<p>text1</p>\n<div>text2</div>text3</body>
```

Is there a way to do this? Any pointer would be appreciated.

**Clarification:**

What I want to do is to retrieve the text of `<p>`-nodes, wherever they are placed. They are often nested within `<div></div>`, or may contain `<div></div>` as in the example above. I prefer excluding the text of `<div>`-nodes nested within `<p>`-nodes, but either is fine. So I wish to exract "text2text4" (or "text2text3text4", with my preference for the former) in the following: `<div>text1<p>text2<div>text3</div>text4</p>text5</div>`.

Comment: Can you replace the leading and trailing Ps with DIV before parsing?

Comment: I think that's the last resort. The files I'm working on include many other `<div></div>` tags that are not within `<p></p>` tags, and so if I replace `<p></p>` with `<div></div>`, it would retrieve the text that I do not wish to retrieve as well. I would nevertheless do it and delete unnecessary text if this is the only option.

Comment: Can you do `html_text(x)` and then `stringr::str_remove(..., html_nodes(x, "div") %>% html_text())`

Comment: It works perfectly in the first example, but unfortunately returns "text1text2text4text5" in the second example (under 'Clarification'). Sorry for the confusion over the specification of the task I'm tackling.

Comment: In XPath, `string(/div/p)` will result in `text2text3text4`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pure xpath solution to get `text2text3text4` as output.

```
string-join(//p/descendant-or-self::*/text(),'')
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: I'm sure this XPath expression works in the way I want it to. Unfortunately, however, the `rvest` package in R (or the `xml2` package underlying it) does not appear to support XPath 2.0, which I believe is necessary to use the `string-join` function. `xml_find_all(x, "string-join(//*[@class='content']/blockquote/text()[normalize-space()], ' ')")` leads to an error: `xmlXPathCompOpEval: function string-join not found`.