# Use GetElementsByClass to find all <div> elements by class name, nested inside a <p> element

Tags: kotlin, jsoup, html-parsing

I am creating a parser using Jsoup in Kotlin

I need to get a inner text of a tag with class "ptrack-content" inside the tag with class "titleCard-synopsis"

When I am trying to getElementsByClass in a element objects that created by a former getElementsByClass, I getting 0 elements

Code:

```kotlin
class NetlifxHtmlParser {

    val html = """
         <div class="titleCardList--metadataWrapper">
            <div class="titleCardList-title"><span class="titleCard-title_text">Map Her</span><span><span class="duration ellipsized">50m</span></span></div>

            <p class="titleCard-synopsis previewModal--small-text">
            <div class="ptrack-content">A hidden map rocks Hartley High as the students' sexcapades are publicly exposed. Caught as the culprit, Amerie becomes an instant social pariah.</div>
            </p>

         </div>
         
          <div class="titleCardList--metadataWrapper">
             <div class="titleCardList-title"><span class="titleCard-title_text">Renaissance Titties</span><span><span class="duration ellipsized">50m</span></span></div>
             <p class="titleCard-synopsis previewModal--small-text">
             <div class="ptrack-content">Amerie, the new outcast, receives a party invitation that gives her butterflies. But when she manages to show up, a bitter surprise awaits.</div>
             </p>
          </div>
    """.trimIndent()

    fun parseEpisode() {
        val doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html)
        val titleCards = doc.getElementsByClass("titleCard-synopsis")
        println("Episode: count titleCard = > ${titleCards.count()}") // 2

        titleCards.forEachIndexed { index, element ->
            val ptrack = element.getElementsByClass("ptrack-content")
            println("Episode: count ptrack = > ${ptrack.count()}") // 0 !!
            println("inner html = > ${ptrack.html()}") // null string !!

        }

    }
}
```

In the above code,

First, I am extracting tags with class name `titleCard-synopsis`.

For that , I using `doc.getElementsByClass("titleCard-synopsis")` which returns 2 element items.

Then, In the List of `titleCard` elements, I am extracting the elements that have `ptrack-content` as Class, by using the same getElementsByClass in each element,

which returns empty list.

Why this is happening ?

My goal is, I need to extract the description text for each title, the stored in the interior tags of p tag with class titleCard-synopsis.

If I try to get directly from "ptrack-content", it's working fine, but this a general class used in many places in the main HTML source. (this is snippet)

I need to get a inner text of a tag with class "ptrack-content" inside the tag with class "titleCard-synopsis"

But in the above method in the code, I am only getting emtpy list.

Why ?

Also note that, if I invoke the `HTML()` method in a element object of `titleCards`(`ptrack.html()`),
I am not getting the inner DIV tag, an empty string!!!

Please guide my to resolve the issue !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

> I need to get a inner text of a tag with class "ptrack-content" inside the tag with class "titleCard-synopsis"

I'm not really familiar with Kotlin, but this should produce the desired output:

```kotlin
val doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html)
val result = doc.select(".titleCard-synopsis + .ptrack-content")

result.forEachIndexed {index, element -> 
    println("${element.html()}")
}
```

[Live example](https://try.jsoup.org/%7E1D9EyxJAPoElZvmkYHnKMW7_Im8)

---

This is an interesting problem!

You basically have an invalid HTML and jsoup is smart enough to auto-correct it for your. Your HTML structure gets altered and suddenly your query does not work.

This is the error:

```html
<p class="titleCard-synopsis previewModal--small-text">
  <div class="ptrack-content">A hidden map rocks Hartley High as the students' sexcapades are publicly exposed. Caught as the culprit, Amerie becomes an instant social pariah.</div>
</p>
```

You can't nest a `<div>` element inside a `<p>` element like that.

> Paragraphs are **block-level elements**, and notably will **automatically close** if another block-level element is parsed before the closing </p> tag. *[Source: [<p>: The Paragraph element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)]*

Also, look at [Nesting block level elements inside the <p> tag... right or wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4291467/6367213)

This is how jsoup parses your tree:

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div class="titleCardList--metadataWrapper">
   <div class="titleCardList-title">
    <span class="titleCard-title_text">Map Her</span><span><span class="duration ellipsized">50m</span></span>
   </div>
   <p class="titleCard-synopsis previewModal--small-text"></p>
   <div class="ptrack-content">
    A hidden map rocks Hartley High as the students' sexcapades are publicly exposed. Caught as the culprit, Amerie becomes an instant social pariah.
   </div>
   <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="titleCardList--metadataWrapper">
   <div class="titleCardList-title">
    <span class="titleCard-title_text">Renaissance Titties</span><span><span class="duration ellipsized">50m</span></span>
   </div>
   <p class="titleCard-synopsis previewModal--small-text"></p>
   <div class="ptrack-content">
    Amerie, the new outcast, receives a party invitation that gives her butterflies. But when she manages to show up, a bitter surprise awaits.
   </div>
   <p></p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, elements with class `titleCard-synopsis` have no children with  class `ptrack-content`.

Comment: Ooooh. The HTML malformed. I copied it from Netflix website via Inspect Element.

Comment: So even Netflix have malformed HTML ??????

Comment: Apparently. Was my answer helpful to you?

Comment: Yes. So My way of parsing don't have any mistake. It fails due to malformed HTML. Right ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right!